# Multithreading or cronjob

Tags: java, linux, multithreading

I have folders which contain xml files. The content of folders is updated (inserted new xml files) as N files per day. I would like to write java program which will get the newest files from folders and do some operations with these files. I have two ways of doing this:

```
  Run java application every t minutes with cronjob.
```

or

```
Multithreaded java application which is run as daemon.
```

Which will be more efficient? Or any ideas, which can help.

Application should run on Linux.

Comment: How does it being multithreaded factor in at all? Seems like the question is really cronjob vs daemon.

Comment: The requirements of the job dictate which one. Daemons are for processing right now, cronjobs run every few minutes.  If it is ok  for several files to sit  unprocessed for 10 minutes (or some other interval) use cronjob.  If the files need to be processed as soon as they are received, use a daemon that monitors the directory for new files with inotify.

Comment: @jimmcnamara what is inotify? can you give resources to using inotify and java

Answer (score 3):

Even if you decided not to go the cron route, your Java application probably wouldn't need to be multithreaded, unless you ended up building a [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)-like scheduler from scratch (which would probably be overkill).

I recommend going with the cron approach for several reasons:

1. Cron is appropriate for the requirements which you've given (i.e. periodic execution without the need to process files as soon as they're received).
2. You're more likely to have bugs around scheduling if you code that logic yourself rather than rely on cron, which is tried and tested.
3. If you use cron and your Java application crashes for some reason, then it won't affect subsequent executions. If you decided to use a long-running Java daemon however, you would probably have to implement a mechanism to monitor its health.

Comment: I think cronjob will have these problems: Let's say cronjob is run every 3 minutes, for processing N files Java application needs 4 minutes. Then while first java application is running the second instance will run which will process some files twice.

Comment: @torayeff If you're keeping track of which files have been processed, you can also keep track of which files are currently being processed as well, to avoid the issue you mentioned.